# how to installing google chrome in kali linux

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, chrome

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

(Reading database ... 237852 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (80.0.3987.149-1) over (80.0.3987.149-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on xdg-utils (>= 1.0.2); however:
  Package xdg-utils is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for kali-menu (2020.1.7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/202097/dependency-problems-installing-google-chrome-package-due-to-xdg-utils-error has the same error. However I would start by trying to install `xdg-utils`

Comment: Rather than installing directly with dpkg I would suggest asking apt to do the heavy lifting: `sudo apt-get install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`.  Make sure you include the `./` or apt-get will do something strange.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if installing `apt install xdg-utils -y` doesn't work try using [SNAP](https://snapcraft.io/chromium) and [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/Home) browser

```
sudo snap install chromium
```